# Please Help Me With Choosing my 1st Telescope

Tags: telescope

I'm going to buy my 1st telescope. With the budget, I've shortlisted some. Tried with the YT videos, reviews and guide. Few things still bugging me. Hope somebody can give me any advice on this. There are two very basic entry-level telescopes I've chosen. Please can somebody advise me which one is good.

**Telescope 1**
-Focal length:900mm
-Lens diameter: 60mm
-Optical system: Reflection
-Eyepiece:SR4mm/H12.5mm/H20mm
-Accuracy:1.842 second of arc
-Horizom:1.2 degree
-Zenital:90 degree
-Finderscope5*24 Optical Magnification
-Magnification:45/65/72/108/135/216/675X

**Telescope 2**
-Optical system: refraction
-Optical coating: multi-layer coating
-Objective lens diameter: 70mm
-Limit magnitude: 12
-Focal length: 300mm
-Focus ratio: 429
-Eyepiece: 6mm 20mm

Really appreciates your help.

Comment: Both look very small, and at that price point you get wobbly mounts, low quality optics and you are probably setting yourself up for disappointment. You are probably better getting a good pair of binoculars rather than these telescopes.  They will show many more stars than can be seen with the naked eye, and have the benefit that they can be used in the daytime too.

Comment: @JamesK - Thank you so much for the reply. Didn't have any idea about it at all. I'll think about it before buying these.